# Generate HTML reports containing info stored in pdf files

Tags: html, perl, r, pdf

I would like to generate an html report containing some outputs (graphs, statistics from R). The graphs are saved in pdf files.

My option : perl script that will generate the html report( by converting the pdf into jpeg)

What other options would be ideal in this case?

I am working in UNIX environment.

Comment: If you desire a simple output, you could have the C, Ruby, R output PDF then run a tool to concatenate all the files sequentially in one new PDF file.

Comment: @EmmadKareem- I am calling all the programs from an R script and have other files as well . I need to add their content in my final report as well..so the pdf file is not a good choice for what I need. I didn't add enough details.sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with R, you can probably look at the [`knitr` package](http://yihui.name/knitr/). R2HTML is based on Sweave, which is not quite extensible, and `knitr` is fully extensible and supports HTML naturually; see a [minimal example](https://github.com/downloads/yihui/knitr/knitr-minimal.html) with [source](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-minimal_knit_.html).

You have many choices on how to save R graphics (pdf, png, jpeg, ...); see the [`dev` option](http://yihui.name/knitr/options) (graphical device). So there is no need for conversion from PDF to other bitmap formats on R's side.

You said you had Ruby and C output as well; I'm not sure how you are going to deal with them: do you want to generate the output dynamically (literate programming) or insert them manually? For the former, you can probably use the R function `system()` to run external programs (e.g. call C to generate PDF and call perl to convert). You can also define [`knitr` hooks](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks) to do these jobs, but you may need to more to learn how hooks work in `knitr`.

Another approach is to convert your PDF output with a batch job, and modify the HTML code, e.g. replace `<img src='foobar.pdf' />` with `<img src='foobar.jpeg' />` in HTML after you have converted all PDF files to JPEG. This should easier.

Comment: @Yihui- thanks for your suggestions .I am running away from the system command or from anything that has "manually" associated. I guess I will have to read in and format the files (C and Ruby outputs)somehow and use the latter suggestion to change it into jpeg.I need it to be as dynamic and general as possible .

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the how the graphs and statistics are created in R, your easiest approach would probably be using the [`R2HTML`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2HTML/) package to generate the HTML directly. This would include an sweave-like approach which would substitute R output in appropriate places in an HTML template.

Also, R can create jpeg files (or gif's) for graphs as easily as it creates PDF's, so that conversion step can be avoided entirely.

Comment: I have mixed outputs (R, Ruby,C) , all displaying graphs in pdfs..I could adjust the ones from my R scripts but not the ones returned by other programs. This is why I was looking for something that could use the outputs as they are. However, the package that you have suggested might be useful for one part.